# How do I add buttons to my Javascript/Jquery Slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, slideshow

So I have a javascript/jquery image slider. Each slide is a <div> element, children of the div "container". Every five seconds, the last slide slides up and the new image fades in. Simple stuff. Here's my code:

```
window.onload = function start() {
    slide();
}

function slide() {
    var num = 0;
    window.setInterval(function () {
        $("#container div:eq(" + num + ")").slideUp(450);
        num = (num + 1) % 4;
        $("#container div:eq(" + num + ")").fadeIn(450);

    }, 5000);
```

So, what do I need to do to add buttons that take you to the next slide and last slide?

Comment: I'm confused; normally when people say "jQuery slider" they are referring to a jQuery UI Slider widget (http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/).  Your code doesn't look like it's using that widget though.  It would be helpful if you could better explain what you are trying to do and what you mean exactly by "slider".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next:

```
$("#next").click(function () {
    $("#container div:eq(" + num + ")").slideUp(450);
    num = (num + 1) % 4;
    $("#container div:eq(" + num + ")").fadeIn(450);
});
```

Last:

```
$("#last").click(function () {
    $("#container div:eq(" + num + ")").slideUp(450);
    num = 4;
    $("#container div:eq(" + num + ")").fadeIn(450);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

*HTML:*

```
<a id="next" href="#">next</a>
<a id="last" href="#">last</a>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var cur = 0;

  var slide = function (n) {
    $("#container div:eq(" + cur + ")").slideUp(450);
    cur = n;
    $("#container div:eq(" + cur + ")").fadeIn(450);
  )

  setInterval(function () { slide((cur + 1) % 4); }, 5000);

  $('#next').click(function () { slide((cur + 1) % 4); });
  $('#last').click(function () { slide(3); });
});
```