# image carousel/slideshow with prev/next button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have follow tutorial from [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_imgdots)

Now I want to improve it with prev / next for the indicators, not for the slider

This is what I want to achieve

[image: example]

Also this is my code

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/0fq0zbew/)

OR

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
     dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-opacity-off", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-opacity-off";
}
```

```css
#indi {
  width: 200px;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="w3-content" style="max-width:1200px">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">

  <div class="w3-row-padding w3-section">
    <div  id="indi" class="w3-col s4">
      <img  class="demo w3-opacity w3-hover-opacity-off" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentDiv(1)">
    </div>
    <div id="indi" class="w3-col s4">
      <img class="demo w3-opacity w3-hover-opacity-off" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentDiv(2)">
    </div>
    <div id="indi" class="w3-col s4">
      <img  class="demo w3-opacity w3-hover-opacity-off" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentDiv(3)">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Thanks before, any help appreciated

Comment: I am not sure what you goal is, just want to mention: If you are trying to learn something, go ahead this is a great way. If you just need some carousel for your project it would be way better to use some already done free script (sugesting slick or flexslder2). You will save yourself a lot of troubles.

Answer (score 2):

Next:

```
$("#next").click(function () {
$("#container div:eq(" + num + ")").slideUp(450);
num = (num + 1) % 4;
$("#container div:eq(" + num + ")").fadeIn(450);
});
```

Last:

```
$("#last").click(function () {
$("#container div:eq(" + num + ")").slideUp(450);
num = 4;
$("#container div:eq(" + num + ")").fadeIn(450);
});
```

This has already been asked and answered - [How do I add buttons to my Javascript/Jquery Slider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695405/how-do-i-add-buttons-to-my-javascript-jquery-slider)

If you need any more specific help please don't hesitate to ask though.